# Could not proxy request /api/products from localhost:3000 to http://127.0.0.1:5000

Tags: reactjs, axios, proxy, localhost

[powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBQeV.png)

[browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzSfO.png)[package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLfBu.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For proxy, you have to set this in your package.json

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3000",
```